# Are there or were there any other conjoined pronoun-verb combinations like "methinks" in English?

Tags: history

And why was this ever considered grammatically correct?  Why not "Ithinks"?

**Edit**:

When I ask "why," I'm wondering for example, whether or not "me" has always been the first-person objective case in English.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

"Methinks" comes from *me þyncð*, meaning *(it) seems to me*. There were originally two distinct but related verbs, *þyncan* (to seem) and *þencan* (to think). The former eventually fell out of favour while the latter became the modern *think*. Commonly used multi-word phrases and terms are often joined into single words over time: look at *almost*, *whoever*, *prithee*, *perhaps*, and countless others. It does seem that relatively few of these involve personal pronouns, though.

Answer (score 3):

One relatively similar historical example that comes to mind is:
***prithee***  - "(I) pray thee" (I beseech thee)

**Updated**:  I was adding a link and an explanation, but I think Jon's answer explains it far better than I could.

Here's the link to an excellent resource that you may find helpful:  http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=methinks