# What part of speech is "methinks"?

Tags: parts-of-speech, dictionaries, archaicisms, early-modern-english, syntactic-analysis

[Dictionaries call this word a verb](http://onelook.com/?w=methinks), but it doesn't seem to behave like any other verb in the English language. [Another question on this site](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/15172) calls it a “conjoined pronoun-verb combination”, which seems nearer the mark to me. What is the reasoning behind the dictionaries’ decision to label *methinks* as a verb?

Comment: It's a contraction. What part of speech is _hasn't_ or _I'm_? And if you knew, what good would it do?

Comment: It's pirate speak :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to understand the syntax of ***methinks*** (in the present tense, that is; ***methought*** is its past tense) is by viewing it as saying “it thinks to me that”, where *thinks* here actually means *seems*, and that leading *me* is a “dative of interest”. Curiously, this is not the only verb to do this.  Its synonym ***meseems*** (along with ***meseemeth*** also in the present and ***meseemed*** in the past tense) works exactly the same way, and for just the same reasons, too.

Like its synonym ***meseems***, ***methinks*** is an archaic impersonal verb with two odd characteristics: despite its impersonality, it stands without a dummy *it*, and it includes a prefix *me* serving as an old “dative of interest”.  That is the sort of dative that occurs when someone says “What happened to your old beater car?” and you say “What, that old thing? It broke down on me one time too many, so I junked it.”

Both ***meseems*** and ***methinks*** were originally written as two separate words: *me seems* and *me thinks* in the modern spelling, and in Old English variously *me þinceþ, me þinceð, me ðincþ, me ðincð*, and many others besides.
 Over the course of time, the original construction became obscure, many variant forms were seen, and they became fused into single words each.

The original ameaning of the Old English verb *þyncan, ðyncan* is **not** the one we use for *think* today, and indeed, this sense of *think* is preserved in modern use only in *methinks* alone.  That original and now obsolete meaning of *think* was to seem or appear, which is exactly what it still means here.  The *seem* meaning of *think* grew rarer after 1250, and disappeared some time after 1400 except in this frozen impersonal expression, *methinks*.  For several centuries its written form varied wildly, because this sort of dative fell out of productive use and people became confused about what was going on and how it all worked.

So *methinks* is a real verb, albeit a curious one. It is in the present tense; its past tense form is *methought*.  Its OED entry ponders the question of its curious syntax, which it calls “obscure”.

> **Pronunciation:**
>     Brit.  /mɪˈθɪŋks/,  /miˈθɪŋks/,  /miːˈθɪŋks/, U.S.  /miˈθɪŋks/,  /məˈθɪŋks/
>
> **Inflections**:   Past tense *methought* Brit.  /mɪˈθɔːt/,  /miːˈθɔːt/, U.S.  /miˈθɔt/,  /məˈθɔt/,  /miˈθɑt/,  /məˈθɑt/.
>
> **Etymology**:  < **me** *pron*.<sup>1</sup> 2a + **think** *v.*<sup>1</sup>, originally as a simple syntactic collocation, in later use apprehended as a single word.
>
> Now *arch*., *poet*., and *regional*.
>
> *impers*. (Used with subordinate clause or parenthetically.)
>
> **a.** In the present tense: ‘it seems to me’.
>
> **b.** In the past tense: ‘it seemed to me’.

The set of forms provided is incredibly long, and contains several entries it thinks may have been transcription errors.

The OED2 has this extended note on its etymology:

> As **think**
>   *v.*<sup>1</sup> did not, exc. in this phrase, survive beyond the 14th c., and had no very wide
>   currency after 1250, the syntax of *methinks* became obscure.  Hence it underwent various alterations of form.  The
>   verb being supposed to be **think**
>   *v.*<sup>2</sup>, it followed that it ought to be in the first person; hence the form *me
>   think*, in which probably the pronoun was still correctly apprehended as a dative.  In the 16-17th c. there occur the
>   forms *my think*, *my thought*(*s*, which are attempts to obtain a normal syntax by taking *think*,
>   *thought*, as sbs.  The curious form *methoughts*, used in the 17th and the first half of the 18th c., prob.
>   owes its *s* to the analogy of the present tense *methinks*.

It then goes on separately document in the present tense all of ***me thinketh***, ***methinks***, ***methink***, and ***my thinks(s***, and in the past tense all of ***methought***, ***methoughts***, ***my thought***.

The OED3 has an even longer etymological note, of which this is just the beginning:

> Although the impersonal use of *think*  with indirect objects other than *me*  persisted until the early 17th cent. (see **think** *v*.<sup>1</sup>), the syntax of this collocation seems to have become to some extent obscure already in Middle English. Hence it underwent various alterations of form.
>
> The present tense (β) form *me think*  apparently shows substitution of the first person singular inflection, perhaps resulting from identification of the verb with **think** *v.*<sup>1</sup>  (compare Middle English forms with *thenk*, *þenk*, etc.); the pronoun was perhaps still apprehended as some kind of indirect object. The form *me þunch*  in *Owl & Nightingale* (Calig.) 1649, 1651 (see quot. c1275 at sense aα. ), is probably to be regarded as a variant (with inverted spelling of *h*  for *þ*) of the α form *me þuncþ*  found elsewhere in this text rather than as an early example of the β forms (the expected first person form would be *þunche*). The Middle English forms *me þinchez*  (c1300 in texts in MS. Laud Misc. 108) and *me þinkez*  (c1330 (c1250) Floris & Blauncheflur (Auch.)) probably show use of the graph *z*  for  /θ/, rather than γ forms.

Comment: Methinks this is the most helpful answer. (Both the others are useful too.)

Comment: Yes, the fate of _meseems_ and _methinks_ (which are historically dative-reflexive experiencer contractions, and synonymous) is one of my favorite classroom examples. In modern English, _think_ has become an active transitive verb with an experiencer subject that takes an object _that_-complement, while _seem_ has become a stative intransitive verb that takes a subject _that_-complement (and requires extraposition).

Comment: @John Lawler. But sometimes intransitive: 'I think, therefore I am.' And: 'What are you doing?' 'I'm thinking.'

Comment: @tchrist What are the acronyms OED2 and OED3 you are using in your answer?

Comment: @HonzaZidek Respectively the second and third editions of the *Oxford English Dictionary*.

Answer (score 6):

The reason it doesn't behave like any other verb is that there is no other verb like it — or at least, no Modern English verb.

It’s an Old English verb which means “it seems to me,” and although it survives to the present (OED has a 1991 citation), it’s listed as “archaic, poetic and regional”.

It’s also listed as an ***impersonal verb*** (a verb with no subject), used with a subordinate clause or parenthetically:

> Methinks I hear some frowning warrior say, “With such unmanly thoughts, away! away!” [J. Cottle, *Poems*, 1796]
>   Ha, ha—go away! ’Tis a tale, methink, Thou joker Kit! [T. Hardy, *Wessex Poems*, 1898]

Dictionaries list it as a verb because that’s what it is.

Comment: Meseems there yet exists at least one verb that behaves the same way. :)

Comment: @tchrist I knew someone would find one; but it's not a ModE verb. And this is the first occurrence I've encountered (although I haven't read the whole of Beowulf, Chaucer or Shakespeare).

Comment: Actually, it is not an Old English verb: the Old English version was *mé þyncþ*.

Answer (score 4):

[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/methinks) and [YD](http://www.yourdictionary.com/methinks) both label it as an [*impersonal verb*](http://www.wisegeek.com/what-is-an-impersonal-verb.htm). Apparently, when listing parts of speech, some dictionaries don't make the distinction between a *verb* and an *impersonal verb*. Methinks that’s because so few verbs are inherently and exclusively impersonal, but it’s hard to say for sure.